# Как передать значения из JS в css?

Tags: javascript, css

```
.anim2 {
  animation-duration: 3s;   //<--вот сюды
  animation-name: oscil2;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Это кусок css-анимации, куда надо вставить переменную numberT.

[А это ссылка, где обясняется, как это сделать, но в JS я ничего не стою](https://css-live.ru/articles/vzaimodejstvie-mezhdu-javascript-i-css-s-pomoshhyu-css-peremennyx.html)

И да, я уже задавал такой вопрос, но тут нужен другой способ

Comment: Вы хотите вставить код с помощью JS, но без JS?

Comment: Из текущего текста вопроса совсем не понятно в чем у Вас проблема.

Comment: вы не можете манипулировать самим стилем (классом) из js. Вы можете либо задать стили для конкретных элементов на странице, у которых есть данный класс, либо добавить `style`-тэг в документ, в котором динамически на js сформировать нужную строку, тогда оно будет подхватываться ко всем элементам с даным классом, даже к тем, которые будут создан ыдинамически. в целом в терминах jquery, например, это будет примерно `$(\`<style type="text/css"> .anim2 { animation-duration: ${numberT}s; }</style>\``).,appendTo('body')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отталкиваясь от ссылки в вопросе, я предположу что вопрос связан с [CSS переменными](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).
А точнее с изменением их при помощи JS.

Для этого можно использовать метод [`.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  let a = document.querySelector('.anim2');
  a.style.setProperty('--dur', '5s');
},6000)
```

```css
.anim2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  animation-duration: var(--dur, 1s);   
  animation-name: oscil2;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes oscil2 {
  0%, 100% {left: 0%;}
  50% {left: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "anim2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  let a = document.querySelector('.anim2');
  a.style["animation-duration"] = '5s';
},6000)
```

```css
.anim2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  animation-duration: 1s;   
  animation-name: oscil2;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes oscil2 {
  from {background: red;}
  to {background: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "anim2"></div>
```